# mysql service always running, not schedule by Kernel scheduler?

Tags: server, process-priority, scheduler

I would like to ask a question:

I have attached screenshot of TOP command of my server. Mysql is always on top and running. While other processes runs/sleeps by ubuntu Scheduler. Even the process KWORKER/U17:2 which has highest priority don't always run.

I start mysql service 4 days earlier than my background process PID: 6741 it only ran 12:58.83 TIME while mysql process PID: 6418 has ran 504:27.83 TIME.

[image: screen shot of server TOP command]

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Mysql is always on top and running." Nothing wrong with that. "While other processes runs/sleeps by ubuntu Scheduler. Even the process KWORKER/U17:2 which has highest priority don't always run." You understand the difference between running a server and using a service? I don't see a problem to fix. If you want mysql to stop consuming CPU you need to stop the service yourself.

Comment: @Rinzwind thanks. My question is that how come it run always while other schedules by Kernel. It don't schedule by kernel?, is it realtime scheduled?

Comment: Because it is a server and not a service. and no it is not scheduled. A server will take any free memory it feels it needs.